# Is there a common method of transcribing prosody?

Tags: phonology, prosody

I've seen diacritics corresponding to tones (in tonal languages), but asides from that I haven't come across a system for transcribing prosody in my studies. Is there a popular convention people use?

Comment: Do you mean all of prosody (syllabification, syllable weight, length, stress, tone) or just intonation?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a way to represent intonation, but if there's any systems that incorporate other prosodic features in addition to intonation I'd still be interested. In class we went over common diacritics, so I have some understanding on how to represent tone, length, and stress.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge as of now there is no united way of transcribing prosodic features of language; however the need for one is critical and therefore there are several meetings being held for designing IPrA (internation prosodic alphabet) [(ucla page for the description of the meetings)](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/ipra_workshop/)

This proposal is going to transcribe prosodic events at the "categorical phonetic" level of AM. For more details you can visit [BU page for the meetings](http://sites.bu.edu/speechprosody2016/)

Also you can see my question [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15710/how-is-ipra-going-to-change-how-we-transcribe-prosody)